# AWS Lambda ClassNotFound when deploying via AWS S3

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-lambda

I have a simple java project that utilises AWS Lambda, I use the necessary maven-shade-plugin config details to package the application to a jar file. I have two options of deploying this jar to AWS Lambda, either by saving the jar/zipped jar in an s3 bucket or running manually update-function-code command.

I ran this command, which works fine, I'm able to test my code. My assumption is that this line zips the jar file located in ./target directory deploys it to the lambda function

```
aws lambda update-function-code --function-name demo-test --zip-file fileb://./target/demo-lambda-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar
```

However, when I attempt the following using AWS S3:

```
aws lambda update-function-code --function-name demo-test --s3-bucket build-owanbe-api-lambdas --s3-key demo-lambda-1.0-SNAPSHOT.zip
```

It returns this error when I try to test my code:

```
Class not found: com.demo.lambda.handlers.DemoHandler: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.demo.lambda.handlers.DemoHandler. Current classpath: file:/var/task/
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> My assumption is that this line zips the jar file located in ./target directory deploys it to the lambda function

That is an incorrect assumption. That line simply uses the .jar file as the zip file. It uploads the .jar file directly. A .jar file is a zip file already. There is no need to zip it up again.

> However, when I attempt the following using AWS S3:
>
> `aws lambda update-function-code --function-name demo-test --s3-bucket build-owanbe-api-lambdas --s3-key demo-lambda-1.0-SNAPSHOT.zip`

You haven't provided any context as to what that .zip file is exactly. I'm going to guess what you did was take the .jar file and zip it up into a .zip file. Instead of doing that, try uploading the .jar file directly to S3 and using that.

Comment: You're right, my assumption were incorrect. I guess I got confused with the fact that you could also provide a .zip file in a lambda function and incorrectly misinterpreted what the command was doing. I zipped the jar file and uploaded so your guess is also correct lol. Thanks